# AJAX content type issue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that looks like this (never mind the laravel syntax)

```
       <form action="{{ URL::route('user-refresh-message') }}" method="post" id="form-user-refresh-message">
            <input id="getterid" name="getterid" type="hidden" value="{{ $profile->user_id }}">
            <input id="getter" name="getter" type="hidden" value="{{ $profile->user->username }}">
            <button type="submit">Refresh</button>
        {{ Form::token() }}
        </form>
```

When I place my code in closure of form on submit event,,, **everything works nicely..**

```
$('#form-user-refresh-message').on('submit', function(){
                $.post(
                    $(this).prop('action'),{
                        "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
                        "getterid": $( '#getterid' ).val(),
                        "getter": $( '#getter' ).val()
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $(".message-area").empty();
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            $(".message-area").append(
                            '<div class="message-item">' +
                            '<div class="message-user">' + item.who + ' said:</div>' +
                            '<div class="message-sent">' + item.when + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="message-viewed"></div>' +
                            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                            '<div class="message-text seen-' + item.seen + '">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                            '</div>');
                        })
                        $('.message-area').scrollTop($('.message-area')[0].scrollHeight);
                    },
                    'json'
                ); 
                return false; 
form );
```

If i place AJAX in a function and call it like this

```
            function refresh_messages() {

                $.post(
                    $(this).prop('action'),{
                        "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
                        "getterid": $( '#getterid' ).val(),
                        "getter": $( '#getter' ).val()
                    },
                    function(data){
                        $(".message-area").empty();
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            $(".message-area").append(
                            '<div class="message-item">' +
                            '<div class="message-user">' + item.who + ' said:</div>' +
                            '<div class="message-sent">' + item.when + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="message-viewed"></div>' +
                            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                            '<div class="message-text seen-' + item.seen + '">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                            '</div>');
                        })
                        $('.message-area').scrollTop($('.message-area')[0].scrollHeight);
                    },
                    'json'
                ); 
                return false;                    
            }


            $('#form-user-refresh-message').on('submit', function(){
                    refresh_messages();
            });
```

I get this in console log

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature.

And I get stuck with the output of the data returned by request on the form action route.

How can I set character encoding in my AJAX request to work properly?

Comment: `this` is the problem. Find out how to use it, and by it I mean this.

Comment: Facepalm! of course! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an encoding issue, rather a javascript scope issue.

In the ajax version of your code, the `$(this).prop('action')` is invalid or rather, it doesn't exist in that context. So your ajax request is being made to a non existing url and resulting 404 not found page's code is loaded as a json response (when it isn't) and you get that error.

so, to fix this, try this:

```
function refresh_messages(targetForm) {
    $.post(
        $(targetForm).prop('action'),{
            "_token": $(targetForm).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
            "getterid": $( '#getterid' ).val(),
            "getter": $( '#getter' ).val()
        },
        function(data){
            $(".message-area").empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $(".message-area").append(
                '<div class="message-item">' +
                '<div class="message-user">' + item.who + ' said:</div>' +
                '<div class="message-sent">' + item.when + '</div>' +
                '<div class="message-viewed"></div>' +
                '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                '<div class="message-text seen-' + item.seen + '">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                '</div>');
            })
            $('.message-area').scrollTop($('.message-area')[0].scrollHeight);
        },
        'json'
    ); 
    return false;                    
}


$('#form-user-refresh-message').on('submit', function() {
    refresh_messages($(this));
});
```

Comment: I still get the same behaviour

Comment: Adding e.preventDefault(); resolved the issue. Thank you. If you post the answer I will credit you with the solution.